# How to delete all `uuid="*-*-*-*-*"` attributes in an XML file using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml

Here is my code in `myfile.jrxml`. All I want to do is to delete all
the `uuid="contained_value"` attributes.

I've searched them with `grep -ir uuid *`.

How to delete them?

```xml
<band height="50">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="8" y="10" width="543" height="1" uuid="cab05ad8-976b-42c9-a158-a6260dd630e1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="38" width="543" height="1" uuid="b673c65e-71e4-4e1c-81e0-ece92c094871"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="38" width="543" height="1" uuid="f87d4dc0-134f-41ae-a828-bca4169d5eb0"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="343" y="13" width="100" height="20" uuid="58c3c4c4-f76e-48a0-897b-2bf129d1fd01"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount /Day]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="449" y="13" width="100" height="20" uuid="8f2e99b5-aa81-49d9-bd0c-a763c37d926e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{day_total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
</band>
```

Comment: Can you post an example output you want?

Comment: <line>
                <reportElement x="8" y="10" width="543" height="1" />
</line>  without the  --> uuid="cab05ad8-976b-42c9-a158-a6260dd630e1" <--

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's#^(([^\s]*\s)?)uuid="[^"]*"(.*)#\1\3#' file.txt
```

- `(([^\s]*\s)?)` matches the portion before the portion to be discarded
- `uuid="[^"]*"` matches the block to be discarded i.e. `uuid="...."`
- `(.*)` gets the rest of the line
- In the replacement we have kept only the desired portion using grouped pattern used in matching

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                            
<band height="50">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="8" y="10" width="543" height="1" uuid="cab05ad8-976b-42c9-a158-a6260dd630e1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="38" width="543" height="1" uuid="b673c65e-71e4-4e1c-81e0-ece92c094871"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="38" width="543" height="1" uuid="f87d4dc0-134f-41ae-a828-bca4169d5eb0"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="343" y="13" width="100" height="20" uuid="58c3c4c4-f76e-48a0-897b-2bf129d1fd01"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount /Day]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="449" y="13" width="100" height="20" uuid="8f2e99b5-aa81-49d9-bd0c-a763c37d926e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{day_total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
</band>


% sed -r 's#^(([^\s]*\s)?)uuid="[^"]*"(.*)#\1\3#' file.txt
<band height="50">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="8" y="10" width="543" height="1" />
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="38" width="543" height="1" />
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="38" width="543" height="1" />
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="343" y="13" width="100" height="20" />
                <text><![CDATA[Amount /Day]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="449" y="13" width="100" height="20" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{day_total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
</band>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer @heemayl .  I've found out alternate solution.In order to delete desire keyword uuid=..... and its associated phase... use -->  %s/\zs\suuid=".\{-}"\ze//g <-- with Ubuntu Vim Editor. Easy open the desire file and use it. :)